# Flash player session doesn't stop on closing balloons

Tags: flash, video, google-maps-api-3, video-player

I made a fullscreen map website. In some interesting point there are baloons opened as placemarks.

- These are Java balloons called `InfoWindows`.
- In some InfoWindows there are `YouTUBE` flash video.
- These video are flash elements in Java InfoWindow.

I don't know the way to tell to flash session to stop when the balloon closes. If I don't stop the flash playing, by the pause click, the song//video continues to run and to download. So if I open four or ten InfoWindows, and I close them with the esc key or the X button, I have the downloads and ten video playing.

Is there a way to tell to flash it is enough? I use Google APIs and the ZhMaps as Joomla component. The website is: [Foto video mappa dell ?isola del Giglio](http://www.gigliotube.it)

An example of what I inserted ina tab of that InfoWindow:

```
<table style="height: 250px; width: 320px;" valign="middle" border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <object width="320" height="180" data="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/JZkfA9lejC0?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/JZkfA9lejC0?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            </object>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flash is history, (thank goodness!) ;-) . Try using [**YouTube's HTML5 player**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) instead:

Comment: I used that code. If I open InfoWindows (but i loose tabs) player stops when the IW is closed, if i use InfoBubbles the player doesn't stop when the InfoBubble is closed.

Comment: Sounds like he answered your question then, since you asked about InfoWindows, not InfoBubbles.